# Does QNX 7.1 supports Web Browser Development

Tags: qnx

I found that QNX 7.0 supports Web Browser Development and since now I am using now QNX 7.1, wanted to know the availability of Web Browser Development support on 7.1

I couldn't find anything from official 7.1 documentation.

Comment: QNX is just an operating system.  Whatever ran on 7.0 is almost certainly going to run on 7.1.

Comment: It is actually not coming with QNX 7.1 setup. And there is no way to download it from the official QNX software center.

But I tried to copy relevant libs and files from QNX 7 and it works .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually not coming with QNX 7.1 setup. And there is no way to download it from the official QNX software center. But I tried to copy relevant libs and files from QNX 7 and it works . Thanks